# How much energy is required to fuse two protons?

Tags: nuclear-physics, coulombs-law, fusion, protons, binding-energy

What is the kinetic temperature required to fuse two protons in a plasma? How much energy does it release? What are the products of the fusion reaction?

Comment: Note that fusing two protons almost always yields a diproton, which is unstable and immediately falls apart.

Comment: How often does it fuse into Deuterium?

Comment: I do not know the exact number, but it is a vanishingly small probability that enables the Sun to continue fusing hydrogen for about 12 billion years.

Answer (score 2):

This is answered in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton%E2%80%93proton_chain_reaction) on proton-proton chain reaction

> The first step in all the branches is the fusion of two protons into deuterium (D). As the protons fuse, one of them undergoes beta plus decay, converting into a neutron by emitting a positron and an electron neutrino

$p + p → D + e^+ + ν_e$

> The positron will probably annihilate with an electron from the environment into two gamma rays. Including this annihilation the whole reaction has a Q value (released energy) of 1.442 MeV.